# ld cannot find cannot find -luser32 (from Eclipse)

Tags: gcc, cygwin, ld

I am trying do CPP development from Eclipse..

I've installed cgywin.. and when try to compile, link any simple `Hello World` App, I got the following while linking ...

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -luser32
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lkernel32
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -ladvapi32
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lshell32
```

Full output:

```
***Build of configuration Debug for project testcpp***
make all 
Building target: testcpp.exe
Invoking: Cygwin C++ Linker
g++  -o "testcpp.exe"  ./src/testcpp.o   
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -luser32
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lkernel32
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -ladvapi32
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lshell32
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [testcpp.exe] Error 1

**** Build Finished ****
```

I think the above libs required by `ld` is win specific ...

I've tried `find / -name *user32*`, the result were ..

```
.....
/usr/i686-pc-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/libuser32.a
......
```

Is this can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the notice above:

```
I've tried find / -name *user32*, the result were ..

.....
/usr/i686-pc-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/libuser32.a
......

Is this can help?
```

It really helped me..

The required libs are included under `mingw` but I am using `cygwin` in eclipse ..
so, under the directory of `cygwin` which is:
`/usr/i686-pc-cygwin`, I've did the following:
`ln -sf ../i686-pc-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib lib;` 
So, now `cgywin` have the required libraries ...

Answer (score 1):

I interrupted setup accidentally, and started to see these:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lshell32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -luser32
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Ran `"cygcheck -c"` resulted in all OK

Ran `"cygcheck -p libuser32.a"` and saw overlap between the two command outputs

```
Found 9 matches for libuser32.a
cygwin32-w32api-runtime-3.1.0-1 - Win32 API import libs for Cygwin 32bit toolchain
cygwin32-w32api-runtime-3.2.0-1 - Win32 API import libs for Cygwin 32bit toolchain
mingw-w32api-4.0-1 - MinGW.org Win32 runtime headers and libraries
mingw64-i686-runtime-3.2.0-1 - MinGW-w64 runtime headers and libraries
mingw64-i686-runtime-3.3.0-1 - MinGW-w64 runtime headers and libraries
mingw64-x86_64-runtime-3.1.0-1 - MinGW-w64 runtime libraries for Win32 64bit target
mingw64-x86_64-runtime-3.2.0-1 - MinGW-w64 runtime libraries for Win32 64bit target
w32api-runtime-3.2.0-1 - MinGW-w64 Windows API import libraries for Cygwin
w32api-runtime-3.3.0-1 - MinGW-w64 Windows API import libraries for Cygwin
```

Ran setup again with Reinstall of w32api-runtime and problem solved.

BGH